# Does GDAX charge network transaction fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, withdrawal, gdax

I've heard its free and when transferring your bitcoin out to an external wallet, but others are saying it's impossible. When I went to withdraw from GDAX I didn't notice and fees.  On the withdrawal screen it also says "BTC network transfers are fast and free."  What is right?

Comment: I don't know about GDAX specifically, but it's pretty common that exchanges pay the network fees on outgoing transactions.  They recoup the costs in the fees that they charge you for trades.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm specifically asking about GDAX

Comment: I sent ETH from GDAX to another exchange last week, didn't charge me for anything at all. Not sure about BTC, as I'm unable to view older transactions right now. Another transaction shows that I sent ETH from Coinbase to my wallet,and got charged 0.00042ETH. So I'm pretty sure ETH is free of charge on GDAX.

Comment: It states that "PROCESSING TIME" - BTC network transfers are fast and free. However I don't have BTC on GDAX right now so I can't test for you.

Answer (score 7):

I could confirm GDAX does not have any network transfer fees. It could be unbelievable, specially if you started with Coinbase(like most people now), but it's the fact, as it's confirmed in all of their withdraw pages 'network transfers are fast and free'!

Comment: I'm amazed GDAX would pay my $21 Bitcoin transfer fee in December 2017

Answer (score 4):

I just bought BTC on Coinbase, I then transferred that BTC to GDAX and then sent the BTC from GDAX to Binance.  NO FEE!!!
If I would have withdrawn in Coinbase to Binance, $200 of BTC would have had a fee of $144!!! CRAZY!

Comment: If you want to save even more you should buy on GDAX, not Coinbase. On GDAX you can buy with a limit order and you'll incur in zero fees (because GDAX uses the maker-taker model). So, essentially, you send money to Coinbase, then move the money to GDAX (instant and free) and then you buy.

Comment: Side note -- you must leave the `Post Only` option checked for this and place your order at a price lower than the current trading price.